What is the purpose of toroidal magnetic field in tokamak fusion device?

From my understanding, pinching plasma to the center is the most important thing. And with Lorentz force, poloidal magnetic field from plasma current itself is pinching it to the center, this should be enough, right?
What about toroidal magnetic field? By Lorentz force again, if electric charge move outward from the center, toroidal field will curve it so it won't go straight outward. But it doesn't make the charge move inward either.
So what is the purpose of toroidal magnetic field?

Maybe think about what would happen if you just had a poloidal field and no toroidal field. What do you think will happen to the confinement? Where will the plasma contact the wall?

The key to the tokamak is that it has two fields that combine together to form one that looks like the stripes on a candy cane. Note the "resulting helical magnetic field" bit on the diagram you included.
The reason for this is a problem originally noted by Fermi. If you consider the toroid solenoid from above, you will note that the ring magnets are closer together on the inside radius - simply a side-effect of the geometry. Fermi noted that particles travelling around the torus will have less magnetic field on them when they are near the outside vs the inside. This will cause the negative and positive charges to drift up and down in opposite directions and ruin confinement.
The solution to this is to mix two fields in the plasma, the primary poloidal one, and a secondary toroidal one. When combined, they form a helical field. In this field, the particles travelling around the torus will follow the lines from the inside where they have more magnetic field, to the outside, where they have less. The result is that the field averages out and reduces the drift.
The next consideration is which of the fields is more powerful. In the early pinch machines like ZETA, the pinch current was king, many times more powerful than the stabilizing fields from the electromagnets outside. This had the huge advantage that the current heated the plasma and the compression multiplied that through the adiabatic process, allowing it to hit fusion temperatures with no other systems. However, it was demonstrated that the current needed to make this happen was driving instabilities that they were never able to solve.
The tokamak addresses this by reducing the pinch current until the resulting field is about the same as the toroidal one from the external magnets. The result is much more "helixy" than the pinch machines, with less current overall, and much less compression (almost none). So they aren't really pinch machines and the pinch current is not paramount. The downside is that without the pinch you need to come up with some other way to heat the plasma, which was the major area of research in the 1970s on PLT and ORMAK and all the rest.
Note that the "outer poloidal field coils" in the diagram are not part of the confinement system per se, they are there to modify the pinch field to offset differences across the plasma due to gravity and offer direct control over the position of the plasma.

excellent exposition, thanks for that! -NN

The toroidal field confines the plasma particles to travel in endless circles, preventing their escape. Unlike simpler "pinch-bottle" field arrangements, there are no "ends" to the field arrangement through which the hot plasma can squirt its way to freedom.
The field also urges the charged particles towards the center of the tokamak ring no matter where they are inside the ring to begin with.
